# SPOJ "ACPC10A - What’s Next" - wrong answer

Tags: java, algorithm, math, output

I have tried the following code, which works well with the custom inputs I tried, however, it's not being accepted and shows -WRONG ANSWER

SPOJ - https://www.spoj.com/problems/ACPC10A/

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void findProgression(int a, int b, int c){
        int diff1 = Math.abs(b-a);
        int diff2 = Math.abs(c-b);
        int nextNumber;
        if(diff1 == diff2){
            nextNumber = c + diff1;
            System.out.println("AP " + nextNumber);
        }else{
            nextNumber = c*b/a;
            System.out.println("GP " + nextNumber);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        while(a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0){
            findProgression(a,b,c);
            a = scan.nextInt();
            b = scan.nextInt();
            c = scan.nextInt();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: check is there any format issue with the output

Comment: I suggest checking what your code outputs for the inputs `-1 -2 -3`. Also, please could you revise the title to something more informative?

Comment: Output format seems to look okay:

Comment: @MarkDickinson 
Thanks! 
I tried with several inputs with a negative number, but not the sequence with all negative integers only.
And it's giving the wrong answer for such a sequence

Comment: Finally passed the challenge!!!
Overlooked the case when the sequence has all negative integers only

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to be taken care of:

1) The difference should be compared as it is and not the absolute value.

2) Take care while calculating the common ratio of GP. Use typecasting.

3) The breaking condition of the solution.

4) Integer overflow.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Solution
{
    public static void findProgression(long a, long b, long c){
        long diff1 = b-a;
        long diff2 = c-b;
        long nextNumber;
        if(diff1 == diff2){
            nextNumber = c + diff1;
            System.out.println("AP " + nextNumber);
        }else{
            nextNumber = (long)((double)c*((double)c/(double)b));
            System.out.println("GP " + nextNumber);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){

            int a = scan.nextInt();
            int b = scan.nextInt();
            int c = scan.nextInt();

            if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0)break;

            findProgression(a, b, c);

        }
    }
}
```